# Ubuntu 18.04 netplan create bridge from wifi to ethernet

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, netplan, network-bridge

I am running ubuntu 18.04 and do not have much experience with networking. This ubuntu server runs on our robot and is supposed to act as a wireless to lan bridge for the rest of the wired modules on the robot. I have been using dd-wrt routers previously in client bridge mode to achieve the same, but they are too inconsistent. An off the shelf extender with ethernet ports is a little expensive and hence i wanted to try this out. I have configured the wireless interface using netplan.

Following are the network interfaces on my server, enp2s0 is the ethernet interface and wlp3s0 is the wifi interface:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::7c0d:f9ff:feb1:68ba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7e:0d:f9:b1:68:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3  bytes 138 (138.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 39  bytes 5047 (5.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.9.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.9.255
        inet6 fe80::42:a6ff:fee9:59a4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:a6:e9:59:a4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1115  bytes 84610 (84.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 843  bytes 77266 (77.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.32.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 169.254.32.255
        ether fc:aa:14:e3:e4:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7e00000-f7e20000  

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.64  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether fc:aa:14:e3:e4:94  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3  bytes 180 (180.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 216  bytes 14171 (14.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 50687  bytes 11888298 (11.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50687  bytes 11888298 (11.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethea1fda5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::94b1:bcff:fe80:d58e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 96:b1:bc:80:d5:8e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 558  bytes 50143 (50.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 486  bytes 45921 (45.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethf80ef47: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::d419:a5ff:fe1d:fb02  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d6:19:a5:1d:fb:02  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 557  bytes 50077 (50.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 486  bytes 45965 (45.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.43  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether d8:fc:93:c5:df:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6318  bytes 5376431 (5.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4444  bytes 851545 (851.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This is my netplan config yaml:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no

  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.44/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      access-points:
        "leibnitz":
          password: "***********"

  bridges:
   br0:
    dhcp4: no
    addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]
    interfaces: [enp2s0,wlp3s0]
    parameters:
      stp: true
      forward-delay: 4
```

The bridge part in the config file is mostly a copy paste from here and there without really understanding whats happening. What i understood is that this creates a bridge between interfaces, and since i have specified that the interfaces to be used are enp2s0 and wlp3s0. It creates a bridge between the 2 interfaces (Sorry if i'm wrong about this). The current status is that i can connect to the internet via my wireless interface but cannot ping the primary router (192.168.0.1) nor any other computers on the same subnet. Following is the output of brctl show:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.7e0df9b168ba       yes             enp2s0
docker0         8000.0242a6e959a4       no              vethea1fda5
                                                        vethf80ef47
```

When i connect a computer(configured with a static IP) to enp2s0, i dont get anything. I cant even ping the computer which is connected to enp2s0. Any advice or help regarding the same would be great.

Comment: What is assigning an IP address to enp2s0?  This does not show in your netplan config.  Also, you are assigning an address and a gateway on wlp3s0; why are you doing this on the wifi interface instead of on the bridge?  Normally you would put the addressing on the bridge interface only.

Comment: @slangasek Thanks for the reply. Like i mentioned earlier, I'm very new to networking side of things on linux. Could you please elaborate on your comment and let me know what needs to be changed. My understanding so far was that since enp2s0 is going to be the "downstream" entity in the bridge, its ip address will be the ip address of the bridge. And wifi is the "upstream" entity whose only job is to route packets to the bridge-ethernet interface. Hence i specified a static ip for wireless.

Comment: Well, that's not how bridges work.  You want your machine to be /either/ a bridge, /or/ a router. Right now your config has elements of both.  You should probably: - move the gateway setting to the bridge interface. - remove the address from the wifi interface. - figure out what is setting an IP address on the ethernet interface (which isn't netplan) and remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so i have got the bridge interface working now. Following is the netplan yaml file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      access-points:
        "leibnitz":
          password: ""

  bridges:
   br0:
    dhcp4: no
    dhcp6: no
    addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.0.1
#    routes:
#     - to: 0.0.0.0/0
#       via: 192.168.0.1/24
    interfaces: [enp2s0,wlp3s0]
    mtu: 1500
    nameservers:
      addresses: [8.8.8.8]
    parameters:
      stp: true
      forward-delay: 4
```

But i had to do some extra configurations in order to add the wireless interface wlp3s0 to the bridge:

```
 $ iw dev wlp3s0 set 4addr on

 $ brctl addif br0 wlp3s0
```

The output of brctl show br0 after the above steps:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.7e0df9b168ba       yes             enp2s0
                                                        wlp3s0
```

After this had to use ebtables to do layer 2 nat, since only wlp3s0 is authenticated with the AP (which is my primary router).

```
ebtables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp3s0 -n snat --to-src  "MAC_OF_WLP3S0" --snat-arp --snat-target ACCEPT

ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p IPv4 -i wlp3s0 --ip-dst 192.168.0.12 -j dnat --to-dst $MAC_OF_CLIENT --dnat-target ACCEPT
ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p ARP -i wlp3s0 --arp-ip-dst 192.168.0.12 -j dnat --to-dst $MAC_OF_CLIENT --dnat-target ACCEPT
```

192.168.0.12 is the ip of the client computer. Please correct me if my understanding of the above commands is wrong. The first ebtables command ensures that every outgoing packet from the bridge interface has the mac address of wlp3s0. And the subsequent 2 commands ensure that when a packet addressed to 192.168.0.12 is received at the input chain its destination mac address is changed to that of the bridge client.

Now the bridge interface works.

```
$ brctl showmacs br0
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer                                                                                                                                         
  2     00:0a:f7:81:da:a3       no                 0.00                                                                                                                                              
  2     24:0a:64:89:33:8d       no               241.86                                                                                                                                              
  2     70:bb:e9:13:b6:03       no                32.02                                                                                                                                              
  1     d8:50:e6:23:32:6b       no                 3.34                                                                                                                                              
  2     d8:fc:93:c5:df:aa       yes                0.00                                                                                                                                              
  2     d8:fc:93:c5:df:aa       yes                0.00                                                                                                                                              
  2     f4:8c:eb:9e:e2:64       no                 0.08                                                                                                                                              
  1     fc:aa:14:e3:e4:94       yes                0.00                                                                                                                                              
  1     fc:aa:14:e3:e4:94       yes                0.00
```

I can ping 8.8.8.8 on the client computer which is connected to the ethernet interface of the bridge. But i dont get internet, i cant browse internet on the client.

This is the route table of the client:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 enp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp4s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp4s0
```

This is the output of ifconfig:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::7c0d:f9ff:feb1:68ba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd01::7c0d:f9ff:feb1:68ba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 7e:0d:f9:b1:68:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 80966  bytes 108616599 (108.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 82286  bytes 10385602 (10.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.9.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.9.255
        inet6 fe80::42:ddff:fe39:8ff0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:dd:39:8f:f0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 38417  bytes 2933398 (2.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28883  bytes 2575833 (2.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether fc:aa:14:e3:e4:94  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3863  bytes 326607 (326.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1662  bytes 125423 (125.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1288744  bytes 205878639 (205.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1288744  bytes 205878639 (205.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth8bdf2aa: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::b834:49ff:fe31:12ac  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ba:34:49:31:12:ac  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 19226  bytes 1736798 (1.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14559  bytes 1297280 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth9e8287f: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::eccb:eaff:fe68:6b60  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:cb:ea:68:6b:60  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 19191  bytes 1734438 (1.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14593  bytes 1299457 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d8:fc:93:c5:df:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 129600  bytes 112940617 (112.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 89885  bytes 13247558 (13.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Following is the yaml file of the client computer:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
   enp4s0:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [192.168.0.12/24]
     gateway: 192.168.0.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

I'm not sure if 192.168.0.1 is the right gateway for the bridge client or should it be the ip of the bridge. I know that bridge is a layer 2 mechanism and it is supposed to be transparent to layer 3, hence all the devices connected to the bridge will have the same gateway as the devices that are connected to the AP outside of the bridge.

How i do i connect the client machine to the internet

Comment: the gateway4 line is apparently deprecated as of Ubuntu 22.04, but otherwise this worked great, thank you so much for posting the solution @Asusrog!